# Get a UITableView to load at the top of the header

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4, ios11

I have a `UITableView` with a giant table header (about half the screen) and the table View rows in 1 section below that.  When I load this view controller from another, it loads to the bottom of the `UITableView` hidding part of the header (depending on how many rows there are).

I tried this:

```
table.setContentOffset(.zero, animated: false);
```

which only works in `viewDidAppear()`. This causes the view to scroll but I just want it to be at the top before it is visible.

Comment: I meant a user clicks ona button and this self.present (the view controller that is a tableview) is called

Comment: Is it a UITableViewController?

Comment: Yes it is a UITableViewController

Comment: And it’s just an ordinary fullscreen presentation? The table view controller isn’t inside a navigation controller or anything?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the table view’s `alwaysBounceVertical` is true.

> table.setContentOffset which only works in viewDidAppear()

Move it to `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: It is set to true but the header is still partially hidden